# Erro com o pandas na hora de compilar o apk com o google colab

Tags: python, pandas, kivy

estou recebendo erro com o panda ao tentar compilar meu apk, mas nao acho uma solução que funcione, alguem sabe como posso consertar esse erro ou tem alguma dica do que pode ser feito?

```
# (list) Application requirements
    # comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
    requirements = python3,kivy==2.1.0, pillow,kivymd==1.0.2, pandas
     
    # (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
    #p4a.branch = develop
  

   
    [INFO]:    Prebuilding cython for arm64-v8a
    [INFO]:    cython has no prebuild_arm64_v8a, skipping
    [INFO]:    Prebuilding Pillow for arm64-v8a
    [INFO]:    Pillow has no prebuild_arm64_v8a, skipping
    [INFO]:    Applying patches for Pillow[arm64-v8a]
    [INFO]:    Pillow already patched, skipping
    [INFO]:    Prebuilding six for arm64-v8a
    [INFO]:    six has no prebuild_arm64_v8a, skipping
    [INFO]:    Prebuilding numpy for arm64-v8a
    [INFO]:    numpy has no prebuild_arm64_v8a, skipping
    [INFO]:    Applying patches for numpy[arm64-v8a]
    [INFO]:    numpy already patched, skipping
    [INFO]:    Prebuilding pyjnius for arm64-v8a
    [INFO]:    pyjnius has no prebuild_arm64_v8a, skipping
    [INFO]:    Applying patches for pyjnius[arm64-v8a]
    [INFO]:    pyjnius already patched, skipping
    [INFO]:    Prebuilding android for arm64-v8a
    [INFO]:    android has no prebuild_arm64_v8a, skipping
    [INFO]:    -> directory context /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/android-sdl2/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/android
    [INFO]:    <- directory context /content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
    [INFO]:    Prebuilding kivy for arm64-v8a
    [INFO]:    kivy has no prebuild_arm64_v8a, skipping
    [INFO]:    Prebuilding pandas for arm64-v8a
    [INFO]:    pandas has no prebuild_arm64_v8a, skipping
    [INFO]:    Applying patches for pandas[arm64-v8a]
    [INFO]:    Applying patch fix_numpy_includes.patch
    [DEBUG]:   -> running patch -t -d /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/pandas/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/pandas -p1 -i /content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/pandas/fix_numpy_includes.patch
    [DEBUG]:    patching file setup.py
    [DEBUG]:    Hunk #1 FAILED at 37.
    [DEBUG]:    Hunk #2 FAILED at 514.
    [DEBUG]:    2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file setup.py.rej
    Exception in thread background thread for pid 10127:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 1641, in wrap
        fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 2569, in background_thread
        handle_exit_code(exit_code)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 2269, in fn
        return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
        raise exc
    sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 
    
      RAN: /usr/bin/patch -t -d /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/pandas/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/pandas -p1 -i /content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/pandas/fix_numpy_includes.patch
    
      STDOUT:
    patching file setup.py
    Hunk #1 FAILED at 37.
    Hunk #2 FAILED at 514.
    2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file setup.py.rej
    
    
      STDERR:
    
    
    [INFO]:    STDOUT:
        patching file setup.py  
    Hunk #1 FAILED at 37.   
    Hunk #2 FAILED at 514.  
    2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file setup.py.rej
    [INFO]:    STDERR:
        
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
        "__main__", mod_spec)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
        exec(code, run_globals)
      File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1297, in <module>
        main()
      File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
        ToolchainCL()
      File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 730, in __init__
        getattr(self, command)(args)
      File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 153, in wrapper_func
        build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
      File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 215, in build_dist_from_args
        args, "ignore_setup_py", False
      File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 498, in build_recipes
        recipe.apply_patches(arch)
      File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 532, in apply_patches
        arch.arch, build_dir=build_dir)
      File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 248, in apply_patch
        "-i", filename, _tail=10)
      File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 167, in shprint
        for line in output:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 915, in next
        self.wait()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 845, in wait
        self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
        raise exc
    sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 
    
      RAN: /usr/bin/patch -t -d /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/pandas/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/pandas -p1 -i /content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/pandas/fix_numpy_includes.patch
    
      STDOUT:
    patching file setup.py
    Hunk #1 FAILED at 37.
    Hunk #2 FAILED at 514.
    2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file setup.py.rej
    
    
      STDERR:
    
    # Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=pesagem --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy==2.1.0,pillow,kivymd==1.0.2,pandas --arch arm64-v8a --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py --debug
    # ENVIRONMENT:
    #     NV_LIBCUBLAS_DEV_VERSION = '11.3.0.106-1'
    #     NV_CUDA_COMPAT_PACKAGE = 'cuda-compat-11-1'
    #     NV_CUDNN_PACKAGE_DEV = 'libcudnn8-dev=8.0.5.39-1+cuda11.1'
    #     PYDEVD_USE_FRAME_EVAL = 'NO'
    #     LD_LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64'
    #     NV_LIBNCCL_DEV_PACKAGE = 'libnccl-dev=2.8.4-1+cuda11.1'
    #     TCLLIBPATH = '/usr/share/tcltk/tcllib1.19'
    #     CLOUDSDK_PYTHON = 'python3'
    #     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
    #     NV_LIBNPP_DEV_PACKAGE = 'libnpp-dev-11-1=11.1.2.301-1'
    #     ENABLE_DIRECTORYPREFETCHER = '1'
    #     HOSTNAME = 'b72cfb513edd'
    #     OLDPWD = '/'
    #     CLOUDSDK_CONFIG = '/content/.config'
    #     USE_AUTH_EPHEM = '1'
    #     NV_LIBNPP_VERSION = '11.1.2.301-1'
    #     NV_NVPROF_DEV_PACKAGE = 'cuda-nvprof-11-1=11.1.105-1'
    #     NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES = 'all'
    #     NV_NVPROF_VERSION = '11.1.105-1'
    #     NV_LIBCUSPARSE_VERSION = '11.3.0.10-1'
    #     DATALAB_SETTINGS_OVERRIDES = '{"kernelManagerProxyPort":6000,"kernelManagerProxyHost":"172.28.0.3","jupyterArgs":["--ip=172.28.0.2"],"debugAdapterMultiplexerPath":"/usr/local/bin/dap_multiplexer","enableLsp":true}'
    #     NV_LIBCUBLAS_DEV_PACKAGE = 'libcublas-dev-11-1=11.3.0.106-1'
    #     ENV = '/root/.bashrc'
    #     PAGER = 'cat'
    #     NCCL_VERSION = '2.8.4-1'
    #     TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH = 'true'
    #     JPY_PARENT_PID = '40'
    #     NO_GCE_CHECK = 'False'
    #     PWD = '/content'
    #     NVARCH = 'x86_64'
    #     NV_LIBCUSPARSE_DEV_VERSION = '11.3.0.10-1'
    #     HOME = '/root'
    #     LAST_FORCED_REBUILD = '20220913'
    #     CLICOLOR = '1'
    #     NV_LIBNCCL_PACKAGE_VERSION = '2.8.4-1'
    #     NV_LIBNCCL_PACKAGE = 'libnccl2=2.8.4-1+cuda11.1'
    #     DEBIAN_FRONTEND = 'noninteractive'
    #     NV_LIBNCCL_DEV_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libnccl-dev'
    #     NV_CUDA_LIB_VERSION = '11.1.1-1'
    #     NV_LIBNPP_PACKAGE = 'libnpp-11-1=11.1.2.301-1'
    #     NV_LIBNCCL_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libnccl2'
    #     LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs'
    #     NV_NVTX_VERSION = '11.1.74-1'
    #     NV_LIBCUBLAS_VERSION = '11.3.0.106-1'
    #     NV_LIBCUBLAS_PACKAGE = 'libcublas-11-1=11.3.0.106-1'
    #     GCE_METADATA_TIMEOUT = '3'
    #     NV_CUDNN_VERSION = '8.0.5.39'
    #     NV_CUDA_CUDART_DEV_VERSION = '11.1.74-1'
    #     GLIBCPP_FORCE_NEW = '1'
    #     TBE_CREDS_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8008'
    #     TERM = 'xterm-color'
    #     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
    #     GCS_READ_CACHE_BLOCK_SIZE_MB = '16'
    #     NV_NVML_DEV_VERSION = '11.1.74-1'
    #     PYTHONWARNINGS = 'ignore:::pip._internal.cli.base_command'
    #     MPLBACKEND = 'module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline'
    #     CUDA_VERSION = '11.1.1'
    #     NV_LIBCUBLAS_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libcublas-11-1'
    #     NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES = 'compute,utility'
    #     TBE_RUNTIME_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8011'
    #     SHLVL = '1'
    #     PYTHONPATH = '/env/python'
    #     NV_LIBCUBLAS_DEV_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libcublas-dev-11-1'
    #     NVIDIA_REQUIRE_CUDA = ('cuda>=11.1 brand=tesla,driver>=418,driver<419 '
     'brand=tesla,driver>=450,driver<451')
    #     NV_LIBNPP_DEV_VERSION = '11.1.2.301-1'
    #     TBE_EPHEM_CREDS_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8009'
    #     NV_CUDA_CUDART_VERSION = '11.1.74-1'
    #     COLAB_GPU = '0'
    #     NV_CUDNN_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libcudnn8'
    #     GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW = '1'
    #     PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/tools/node/bin:/tools/google-cloud-sdk/bin'
    #     NV_LIBNCCL_DEV_PACKAGE_VERSION = '2.8.4-1'
    #     LD_PRELOAD = '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtcmalloc.so.4'
    #     NV_CUDNN_PACKAGE = 'libcudnn8=8.0.5.39-1+cuda11.1'
    #     GIT_PAGER = 'cat'
    #     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
    #     PACKAGES_PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/packages'
    #     ANDROIDSDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
    #     ANDROIDNDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r23b'
    #     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
    #     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
    # 
    # Buildozer failed to execute the last command
    # The error might be hidden in the log above this error
    # Please read the full log, and search for it before
    # raising an issue with buildozer itself.
    # In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Comment: Veja se este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282617/hunk-1-failed-at-1-whats-that-mean) ajuda. Parece que é alguma coisa relacionada com espaços no patch. Pode ser também que tenha que substituir `^M` ou `^M$` por ENTER

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção amigo, eu ja consegui fazer funcionar adicionando um 'True' na linhas 311:   #p4a.local_recipes = True no arquivo  buildozer.spec

Answer (score 0):

Consegui fazer funcionar adicionando um 'True' na linhas 311: #p4a.local_recipes = True no arquivo buildozer.spec
e deixei como 'master'  #p4a.branch = master, não entendo direito o pq mas funcionou perfeitamente com o pandas na hora de roda o apk no celular.